# kdiff3 merge does not work

Tags: kdiff3

While using [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to resolve merge conflicts, how do I save the resolved copy of the **A** and **B** versions?

I open [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to resolve merge conflicts. I am able to resolve each conflict by selecting the desired version. When I have resolved all of the conflicts, I click the `merge` button. Then I try to save, but a prompt appears saying that there merge conflicts are still present.

Answer (score 10):

Clicking the `merge` button in [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) restarts the merge process.

To continue the merge, you must save the file after resolving the merge conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

The three sections you see at the top of the window are section A, section B and section C.

Search for the section at the bottom left which shows the text "merge conflicts"
[image]

Right click on that line and select the parts from B and C that you want to merge, save and exit.
[image]